# Box shadow effect not working for slideshow

Tags: jquery, css, html, slider, slideshow

I have a very simple slider and I am trying to implement the #5 at this link http://www.paulund.co.uk/creating-different-css3-box-shadows-effects for all of the images in the slideshow. I'm not having much luck! I can't get anything to show up at all. Thanks for any help in advance.

the slide css:

```
.blueberry { margin: 0 auto; padding-bottom:25px; width:auto;}

.blueberry .slides {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.blueberry .slides li {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.blueberry .slides li img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: none;
}

.blueberry .slides li.active { display: block; position: relative; }
.blueberry .crop li img { width: auto; }

.blueberry .pager {
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}

.blueberry .pager li { display: inline-block; }
.blueberry .pager li a,
.blueberry .pager li a span {
    display: block;
    height: 4px;
    width: 4px;
}

.blueberry .pager li a {
    padding: 18px 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -o-border-radius: 6px;
    -ms-border-radius: 6px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;

}

.blueberry .pager li a span {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #c0c0c0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    -o-border-radius: 2px;
    -ms-border-radius: 2px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;

}

.blueberry .pager li.active a span { 
background: #404040; 

}

.shadow:before, .shadow:after
{
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 25px;
  left: -25px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width:400px;
  background: #777;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 35px 20px #777;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 35px 20px #777;
  box-shadow: 0 35px 20px #777;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-8deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-8deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-8deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-8deg);
  transform: rotate(-8deg);
}

.shadow:after {

  -webkit-transform: rotate(8deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(8deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(8deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(8deg);
  transform: rotate(8deg);
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="blueberry">
  <ul class="slides shadow">
    <li><img src="images/avatar.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/ironman.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/tron.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/greenhornet.jpg" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the class "active" to one of the li's to see anything. Then go back to that site and look at the before/after code for the shadow effect. It's not anywhere in your CSS at the moment

Okay, cool. Look at Wolf's jsfiddle, notice that the shadow is being applied to an h3, not the image or the li itself. If you do apply it to the li you'll get some pretty funky weirdness.

Comment: I applied the shadow directly to the blueberry class and it worked like a charm. Thanks! I was trying to apply it to the li and img. I do not have enough reputation to up vote you or I would.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/CWTHD/2/)

Here i have modified the CSS for class `box`

```
.box {
    width:70%;
    height:200px;
    background:#FFF;
    margin:40px auto;
    background-image:url('http://unleashthefanboy.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/MARK2.jpg');
    background-color:#cccccc;
    background-size:100%; 
}
```